# How to filter Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection') by custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I want to apply some custom filter on `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection')` search collection.

For this I have created a custom module and override `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer` `getProductCollection` function.

How to apply `->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',array('in' => $array))`?

When I try to apply above filter to catalogsearch collection then it returns error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.custom_attribute' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100000) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='33'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE 1=1 AND ( final_price >= "10000" AND final_price <= "145268" ) AND (e.custom_attribute IN(190, 1247, 2862, 2863, 2864)) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100000) + 1 ORDER BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100000) + 1 ASC
```

`->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',array('in' => $array))` it returns unknown column `e.custom_attribute` error.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: have you tried to var_dump the collection?

Comment: Yes, using `Mage::log(print_r($collection->getSelect()->__toString(), 1), null, 'search.log');` it dump query in `var/log/search.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use above to filter,

```
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','9');
```

Also you can try

```
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', '9');
```

Comment: It returns error unknown column `attribute_set_id`.

Comment: Okay, do you have added this attribute in your "Prouduct" attribute set from admin panel or manually ?

Comment: Yes, and when I dump query, this also return `attribute_set_id` in select query.

Comment: Okay got the issue, refer my new answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems a re-indexing issue. Try the following Steps to Re-index:

1. Magento Admin Panel
2. System
3. Index Management
4. Select All
5. Submit (Re-index Data)

Comment: Hello, I tried but it is not working , and also when I trying to group by name this also return unknown column `e.name` exception for `$collection->getSelect()->group('e.name');`, while in other collection like `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` both filter are working.